# UDP packet loss in application layer at high speeds in WinRT?

Tags: c#, network-programming, udp, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

This is a really bizarre bug I've come across and it appears to be a limitation of the WinRT framework. The code to replicate this issue would take up too much space, so I will describe it as best I can. In my application, the UI consists of some static TextBlocks, an indeterminate progress bar, a determinate progress bar, and a status TextBlock that is updated every second.

When downloading UDP packets using `DatagramSocket` at high speeds (~30Mbps), there is significant packet loss (>60%) that occurs between the network layer and the application layer. I say that it is in the application layer, because running a packet trace while the download is being performed (such as [netsh trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd569142%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) reveals all of the packets that the network layer is receiving that the application layer is not.

I can only assume that the WinRT framework isn't able to keep up with the speed at which the `MessageReceived` callback function needs to be fired off. I have not found any means of performing any sort of buffering on the UDP download. The only way I have found to receive the UDP packets is the callback function, which is fired off for each individual packet.

Again, this application layer packet loss occurs at download speed around 30Mbps. It is not seen at slower speed like 10Mbps.

Has anyone else encountered this problem, or does anyone know a way to perform buffering when performing a UDP download?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working on this issue for about a week now and have determined that the vast majority of the packet loss is due to the presence of the progress bars in the UI. The determinate progress bar doesn't even have to be updated--the fact that it exists in the UI is enough to cause the significant packet loss. Without the progress bars, I was able to reduce the packet loss to about 2% (from >60%).

I also wrote a thin client to test the issue that wasn't burdened with the rest of my application's structure. The thin client implemented only the UDP download functionality with hardcoded values. Even with absolutely no UI, I was still seeing 0.05% packet loss in the application layer, so this really does seem to be an issue in the WinRT framework. When I added just an indeterminate progress bar to the thin client, the packet loss jumped to >30%.

Unless someone knows of another method for performing the receive portion of the UDP download (other than the `MessageReceived` callback), or until this issue is resolved in the WinRT framework, it appears that you should expect at least some packet loss between the network layer and the application layer when doing high speed UDP downloads. Also, progress bars should not be used when a UDP download is being performed.

**TL;DR:** Don't use progress bars with UDP download in WinRT and expect some packet loss at high speeds regardless.

Comment: "the fact that it exists in the UI is enough to cause the significant packet loss" - That is absolutely bizarre! Considered opening it as a Microsoft Connect issue?

Comment: It really is! Yes, I'm going to send them my thin client package, so they can see it being reproduced.

Comment: @didierc The packet loss I'm talking about is not occurring on the network. It's occurring between the network layer and the application layer. The netsh traces prove this. The application layer should be receiving all of the packets that the network layer is receiving. To answer your question, I have tried using TCP and had no problems, but UDP is a requirement for this portion of my application.

Comment: I don't think that my question is less relevant: it should be a good indicator in your bug report. But if UDP is unreliable, must the network stack have a strong commitment to pass all the packets it receives to the app layer? Apparently, the WinRT choose to drop some packets to preserve the responsiveness of the UI (that's my interpretation of your description of the phenomenom, feel free to think otherwise).

Comment: You make a good point, and your interpretation definitely sounds plausible--especially with Microsoft's repeated emphasis on UI responsiveness in WinRT. However, we haven't hit this roadblock in our other clients (iOS, Android, WP7, etc.). I think if WinRT allowed access to an input buffer instead of confining access to a single packet per callback, this issue could be avoided. We solved a similar issue to this in our WP7 client using this method, but it isn't an option in WinRT.